# after migrating from Apache2.4 to OHS(Oracle HTTPS server) I get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: oracle, php-7, apache2.4, php-7.1, oracle-http-server

After migrating from Apache 2.4 to OHS(Oracle HTTPS server) 
I get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

I am using PHP 7 version

when I entered command php -m I can see that OCI8 is installed
[image]

When I use Apache I am able to connect to oracle database, But when I try the same code using OHS(Oracle HTTPS server) I get this error 
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()"
I can see all the DLL's are located

When I run the below command I get "TRUE" as output
php -r "var_dump(function_exists('oci_connect'));"

Can you please help me

Comment: Look at the output of a `<?php phpinfo();?>` that will show you what the web server thinks is activated. Also check that the server is getting its `php.ini` from that same place as the PHP CLI

Comment: Thanks, when I compared the both php.ini files 
1) I can find OCI8 enabled
2)For OHS php.ini file i cannot the see the OCI8 section

Can you please suggest how can we enable ?

Comment: Yes, edit the `php.ini` file and add the `extention=....` to match the one used by the CLI

Comment: but both of them are using same php.ini file (C:/PHP7) folder, 
Still i am not able to understand why there is a difference in php.ini file.